# Reducing load on the main thread when using dispatch_get_main_queue()

Tags: iphone, grand-central-dispatch

I'm generating a lot of thumbnails in my iPhone app using GCD. I have something that look like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // generate thumbnail

    // store thumbnail

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // display thumbnail (cellForRowAtIndexPath and cell.imageView.image = ..
    });
);
```

It works pretty well, but I would like to lower the priority for the display block, in order to have a more responsive UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main queue (associated with the main thread) doesn't have a priority. You can't change its priority.

Anyway, you may instead post a `NSNotification` using the `NSPostWhenIdle` posting style. This will allow your code to be executed only when your app have some idle time. See [here in the documentation / dedicated Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/UnblockUI.html) about such techniques.